# NodeJS - jQuery DELETE Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to send a DELETE request on a button click, but I'm not sure if my jQuery is set up and despite using routing that is for the delete method, I am still getting GET request errors `Cannot GET /app/delete/1`. Am I on the right track with my jQuery and how do I prevent this GET request?

Route:

```
appRoutes.route('app/delete/:testId')

    .delete(function(req, res){
        models.Test.destroy({
            where: {
                userId: req.user.user_id,
                testId: req.params.testId           
            }
        }).then(function(){
            res.redirect('/app');
        });
    });
```

Link:

```
<a href="/app/delete/{{test.testId}}" id="test-delete-link">Delete</a>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#test-delete-link').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    url: '/app/delete/{{test.testId}}'
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that when a link is clicked, it uses `GET`. When your link is clicked, two things are happening.

- The `click` event is triggered and jQuery sends the `DELETE` request.
- The browser sends a `GET` request to the same path because it is a link.

To fix this, set the `href` property of the link to `"javascript:void(0);"`. This makes it so that clicking the link does nothing except what is specified in the `click` event.

As a side note, I would change the path of the request from `/app/delete/:testId` to `/app/:testId`. The way it is right now is redundant, as you are saying `DELETE /app/delete/1`. The more RESTful way to do it is `DELETE /app/1`.

Comment: Hey @voidpigeon, thanks for the response. Your answer worked with making the DELET request, but I'm curious why my redirect is never triggered. Should I use the ajax method?

Comment: @cphill You should use the ajax method. The reason the redirect does not work is that it is redirecting the ajax request, not the page the browser is on. Instead of calling `redirect` on the server, redirect on the client after getting a response from the server.